# IN Clause from an included table, doesn't works as expected

Tags: c#, linq, in-clause

I'm trying to do this:

```
        var results = (from s in db.ExampleMaster
                           .Include("State")
                           .Include("Group")
                           .Where("it.Group.IdGroup in {1,2,3,4,5}")
                           .Where("it.IdState in {1,2}")
                            select s);
```

The Schema:

```
ExampleMaster:
    IdExampleMaster int,
    IdState int

State:
    IdState int,
    Description varchar(100)

Group:
    IdGroup int
    IdExampleMaster int
```

The SQL Desired is like:

```
SELECT * FROM ExampleMaster e
inner join State s on s.IdState = e.IdState
Inner join Group g on e.IdExampleMaster = g.IdExampleMaster 
where g.IdGroup in (1,2,3,4,5) and e.IdState in (1,2)
```

The SQL Generated is like:

```
SELECT *
    FROM ExampleMaster AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IdExampleMaster] = [Extent2].[IdGroup]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[IdGroup] = [Extent3].[IdGroup]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[IdGroup] = [Extent4].[IdGroup]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent2].[IdGroup] = [Extent5].[IdGroup]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent2].[IdGroup] = [Extent6].[IdGroup]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent2].[IdGroup] = [Extent7].[IdGroup]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[State] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent1].[IdState] = [Extent8].[IdState]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[IdState] IN (1,2)) AND ([Extent3].[IdGroup] = 1 OR [Extent4].[IdGroup] = 2 OR [Extent5].[IdGroup] = 3 OR [Extent6].[IdGroup] = 4 OR [Extent7].[IdGroup] = 5) ) AS [Filter1]
```

I don't understand why the state case (no Included table required) works well with IN clause and the Group make so many joins than items on the list and even that it doesn't works as expected.

Any idea?

---

### **EDITED**

I found an error on my database schema, now the error I get with

```
.Where("it.Group.IdGroup in {1,2,3,4,5}")
```

Is

> 'IdGroup' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[myModel.Group(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a subquery to iterate over the collection

Comment: Could we see some relevant db schema details?

Comment: Thank, I appended the schema and a query desired example

Comment: I believe it's because the directions of the relationships between the tables are different; ExampleMaster is in the middle of the graph rather than being the root for both the other tables and it's likely that the query generation engine handles these two scenarios differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out:

linq:

```
from e in ExampleMaster
join s in State on e.IdState equals s.IdState
join g in Group on e.IdExampleMaster = g.IdExampleMaster
where g.IdGroup.In(1,2,3,4,5) && e.IdState.In(1,2)
select e;
```

Create an extension method for In:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static bool In(this int @this, params int[] values)
    {
      return values.Contains(@this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use "Contains" method because I'm using ToPagedList() and that cannot be translated into a store expression

Answer (score 0):

LINQPad code which seems to give expected result according to question

(schema names: 'master','state','group' pluralized by LINQPad itself)

```
Masters
    .Join(
        States, 
        master => master.Idstate, 
        state => state.Idstate,
        (master,state) => new
            {
                idmaster = master.Idmaster,
                idstate = state.Idstate,
                descr = state.Descr
            }
        )
    .Join(
        Groups,
        firstJoin => firstJoin.idmaster,
        groups=>groups.Idmaster,
        (firstJoin, groups) => new
            {
                masterid = firstJoin.idmaster,
                stateid = firstJoin.idstate,
                groupid = groups.Idgroup,
                descr = firstJoin.descr
            }
        )
    .Where(x => new int?[]{1,2,3,4,5}.ToList().Contains(x.groupid))
    .Where(x => new int?[]{1,2}.ToList().Contains(x.stateid))
```